# getting the error code of a sub-command using $(...)

Tags: bash, exit-code

In this code :

```sh
echo hello > hello.txt
read X <<< $(grep hello hello.txt)
echo $?
```

`$?` refers to the exit code of the read statement which is 0.  Is there a way to know if the `grep` failed (e.g., if `hello.txt` has been deleted by another process) without splitting the `read` and `grep` in two statements (i.e., first `grep` then check `$?` then `read`).

Comment: Why `read X <<< $()`? Why not just `X=$()`? What part of `read` do you need?

Comment: My mystake, this was a silly example.  Basically I want to do something like `command $(grep hello hello.txt)` and then check if the `grep` succeeded.

Comment: Use a temporary variable. `tmp=$(grep hello hello.txt); grep_exit_status=$?; command "$tmp"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll do that. But I was wondering if there is some form of "stack of return codes" to get codes of older commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `process substitution` instead of `command substitution + here string`:

```
read X < <(grep 'hello' hello.txt)
```

This will get you `1` when using `echo $?`.

PS: If `grep` fails it will write an error on your terminal.

If you want to suppress error then use:

```
read X < <(grep 'hello' hello.txt 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
X=$(grep hello hello.txt)
echo $?
```

For general case where you want to use read to do word splitting, then use a temporary variable:

```
tmp=$(grep hello hello.txt)
echo $?
IFS=' ' read -r name something somethingelse <<<"$tmp"
```

Comment: You guys are quick!